# CSS grid sorting

Tags: css, css-grid

I got something like:

```css
div:not(.mega) { background: yellow; width:150px; }
.right { background: red !important; }
/* // */

.mega {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
}

.left {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.right {
  grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="mega">
  <div class="left">One</div>
  <div class="right">Two</div>
  <div class="left">Three</div>
  <div class="left">Four</div>
  <div class="right">Five</div>
  <div class="right">Six</div>
  <div class="left">Seven</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way, using CSS grid to make it look like:

```
One      Two
Three    Five
Four     Six
Seven
```

These are my attempts to do this, but the elements do not follow one after another:

https://jsfiddle.net/e7vt6jmn/

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please try something before asking a question or add a code snippet of what you have tried. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: Are your elements deliberately out of order? Reading left-to-right `Four` and `Five` seem misplaced - which I imagine is why you're asking this question - but is there a programmatic/logical reason for this?

Comment: @SuperDJ I was looking on the web, but I could not find a solution :/ I added a snippet

Comment: @DavidThomas this is the point that elements can have a different order

Comment: CSS-Grid does permit ordering of elements **but** you would probably need to order each one individualy, and your current CSS would have to be abandoned. i suspect that this is a *"masonry"* question and your may need to re-think your layout methodology.

Comment: Sure, but what do you base the order-change on? The element? The class? The content? The size of the element or content..?

Answer (score 0):

CSS-Grid does permit ordering of elements but you would probably need to `order` each one individualy, and your current CSS would have to be abandoned.

In this **specific** instance you can manage this using `nth-child` and subsequent sibling selectors.

```css
div:not(.mega) {
  background: yellow;
  width: 150px;
}

.right {
  background: red !important;
}

.mega {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px;
}

div {
  order: 1;
}

div:nth-child(5) {
  order: 2;
}

div:nth-child(4),
div:nth-child(5)~div {
  order: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="mega">
  <div class="left">One</div>
  <div class="right">Two</div>
  <div class="left">Three</div>
  <div class="left">Four</div>
  <div class="right">Five</div>
  <div class="right">Six</div>
  <div class="left">Seven</div>
</div>
```